# flask inquiry css file report error

Tags: python, unicode, flask

I am using the Flask, the version is 0.10_dev
here  is  my app code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
     render_template, flash, _app_ctx_stack

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    # DATABASE = '/flaskr.db',
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY = 'freight price',
    USERNAME = 'admin',
    PASSWORD = 'Jake'
    )

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', page = "index")

# @app.route('/rate')
# def rate():
#     return render_template('rate.html', page = "rate")

# @app.route('/update')
# def update():
#     return render_template('update.html', page = "update")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is  my  template code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hyun Young | {{ page }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>{% block body %}{% endblock %}    
</body>
</html>
```

when I was using chrome to check the error, chrome told  me  that  there  is  an 500 HTTP states code.And I tried to check the css file directly. There was an error report

> UnicodeDecodeError UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte
>   0xd4 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__ return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 822, in send_static_file cache_timeout=cache_timeout) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 612, in send_from_directory filename = safe_join(directory, filename) File "C:\Python27\lib\site--packages\flask\helpers.py", line 582, in safe_join return os.path.join(directory, filename)     
File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 108, in join Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this framepath += "\\" + b
```

Comment: I'd check the python file if there are no special characters (like if you copy-pasted `'` from some page then it might be unicode)

Comment: @OfirIsrael Dear Ofir, Thanks for reply. I have already found out the error. Because of the path of my folder contains Chinese characters.